# tenserflow quites before it is done installing

Tags: python

When I do

```
pip install tenserflow
```

tensorflow stops before is is finished, no message saying successful
( i tried this several times thought maybe it was a network issue)

```
Successfully installed absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.8.0 gast-0.2.2 google-pasta-0.1.7 grpcio-1.23.0 h5py-2.9.0 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 markdown-3.1.1 numpy-1.17.0 protobuf-3.9.1 six-1.12.0 tensorboard-1.14.0 tensorflow-1.14.0 tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.15.5 wheel-0.33.6 wrapt-1.11.2
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
( no message saying successful)
```

When I try to import keras i get a bunch of errors, Im assuming it is because tenser flow did not do the complete instalation

```
import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\nur6\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
```

Comment: How can you have 3k reputation and still format your question in such a way?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? or are you still struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are simply warnings (So you can safely ignore them, they are not actual errors), your numpy version is not compatible with the tensorflow version you are using. Tensorflow did install correctly; as seen in the outpout from pip:

```
**Successfully installed** absl-py-0.7.1 astor-0.8.0 gast-0.2.2 google-pasta-0.1.7 grpcio-1.23.0 h5py-2.9.0 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.0 markdown-3.1.1 numpy-1.17.0 protobuf-3.9.1 six-1.12.0 tensorboard-1.14.0 ***tensorflow-1.14.0*** tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-0.15.5 wheel-0.33.6 wrapt-1.11.2 You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.2.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Either upgrade tensorflow or downgrade numpy and the warnings will disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the help how do i

Comment: You're welcome. How do you what? If you feel my answer helped you you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).